# Yarn/Node - JavaScript - Issues with Import and Export

Tags: javascript, import, export, node-modules, yarnpkg

I want simply import a function from an another file and I'm getting this error message:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I'm not using any html file. I'm using only js files with webpack that returns the result on the console with `yarn start`

**Here is the code of the file that contains the function I want to export:**

```
export function assert(value, desc) {
  return value ? console.log(desc) : console.log('fail')
}
```

**Here is the code of the file that I want to import the function:**

```
import {assert} from './assert.js'

function juggle() {
  var result = 0;
  for(var n=0; n < arguments.length; n++) {
    result += arguments[n]
  }

  this.result = result
}

var ninja1 = {}
var ninja2 = {}

juggle.apply(ninja1, [1,2,3,4])
juggle.call(ninja2, 5,6,7,8)

assert(ninja1.result === 10, "juggled via apply")
assert(ninja2.result === 26, "juggled via call")
```

**Here is my `package.json`:**

I don't know if it is userful to solve this issue, but here is, if you want to see it.

```
 {
  "name": "c",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {   
    "start": "node Cap_03/01_apply_e_call.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"   
     },
  "author": "",  
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "type": "module",  
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.41.2"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: Do you have `type="module"` in your script tag?

Comment: No I don't have. I'm not using any html file. I'm doing all the things only with js files. Because it isn't an app. It is only some simple files to study the language. Is it any way to do it? Using only js files?

Comment: Via node? Maybe you just need to add the `"type": "module"` in package.json. Check this out: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling

Comment: @dork It is continuing not working.I tested it in my code. I edited the question with your suggest and it continues showing the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

As of Node 13.2.0+

Verify that you have the latest version of Node installed. Simply do one of the following:

- Add "type": "module" to the nearest parent package.json. With this, all .js and .mjs files are interpreted as ES modules. You can interpret individual files as CommonJS by using the .cjs extension.

OR

- Explicitly name files with the .mjs extension. All other files, such as .js will be interpreted as CommonJS, which is the default if type is not defined in package.json.

If you use an [older Node version or have to](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_code_import_code_statements)

> import statements are permitted only in ES modules.
>  
>    For similar functionality in CommonJS, see import().

To make Node treat your file as a ES module [you need to](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling)

- add "type": "module" to package.json
- add "--experimental-modules" flag to the node call